# Date saved in 7 bytes. Need deciphering this date

Tags: c#, byte

I have to decipher the date written in bytes.
I have 7 bytes:

```
byte[] array = new byte[] {255,2,217,16,37,7,35};
```

Which mean probably from left to right:

```
historyEventIndexE_HOUR = 0,
historyEventIndexE_MINUTE = 1,
historyEventIndexE_SECOND = 2,
historyEventIndexE_DAY = 3,
historyEventIndexE_MONTH = 4,
historyEventIndexE_YEAR = 5,
historyEventIndexE_MAX = 6
```

or

```
TabTime[YEARS]  = RxBuf0[2];//y
TabTime[MONTHS] = RxBuf0[3];//m
TabTime[DATE]   = RxBuf0[4];//d
TabTime[HOURS]  = RxBuf0[5];//h
TabTime[MINUTES]= RxBuf0[6];//m
TabTime[SECONDS]= RxBuf0[7];//s
TabTime[DAYS]   = RxBuf0[8];//d
```

I think max should mean day of the week.
Maybe someone have idea how read this data from this bytes?

Comment: Where did the date come from in the first place? Oracle databases store dates in a 7 byte format, but the values dont really work for this example

Comment: @richzilla i dont know, i dont have access to program which code this data. I ask because maybe it looks like some common pattern. And someone know how read it.

Comment: Try converting many dates and see if you find a pattern.  One sample is not enough.  I tried a few things and did not get a valid date.  The 255 is not making any sense.

Comment: It should be change from Decimal on Hex. And 255 should mean day of the week, but is enough for me to know data.